# MYSQL Select 3 days before the current date up to the last record

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How can I select in mysql the records 3 days that has missed a date.
For instance, the current date is: `2013-09-24` - minus 3 days, it should select the dates from
`2013-09-21` up to the last record.

I found these: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)` to select the dates for the last 3 days, but this is not what what I'm looking.

Comment: On the contrary, that is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: No, it that selects dates from Current Date - 3 days. I' looking for -3 days upto the last record.

Comment: use date field from db then

Comment: How are those two conditions different?

Comment: instead of CURDATE() use the date of the last record.

Comment: Got these query working: `event_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)` It works now

Comment: @winona Wouldn't you want `>=`?

Comment: `>=` select between the last 3 days upto the current date.